# UINavigationController has to call method when updates view with a new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationControllerSubclass. When view controller is popped to some new view controller (by `navigationController.popViewController`, `navigationController.popToRootViewController` or even by `manually sliding from left to right`)

I need to call inside my navigation controller:

```
viewController.newTopViewController.updateBackButtonTitle()
```

What is the best approach to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it would be the following:

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func popToRootViewController(animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]? {
        shouldUpdateBackButtonTitle()
        return super.popToRootViewController(animated: animated)
    }

    override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
        shouldUpdateBackButtonTitle()
        return super.popViewController(animated: animated)
    }

    private func shouldUpdateBackButtonTitle() {
        viewController.newTopViewController.updateBackButtonTitle()
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, but I need to add function popToViewController and self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.addTarget and have this logic there too. I just thought that it might be a better solution

Comment: Im afraid there isn't a single method where you can handle all cases. But it might worth checking UINavigationController documentation extensively.

Comment: Did you find any solution or approach for your problem? @PaulT.

Comment: Frankly speaking I already don't remember how I did that, so I'm gonna mark your question as correct

Answer (score 0):

When you return to viewController call this viewWillAppear method. Inside that function you can check your rootviewController then you can call your

> updateBackbuttonTitle()< 
>   function.

Comment: no, I have 100 view controllers and don't have base view controller, I need to call this method from navigation controller (viewController->function)

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewWillAppear method, and easily update UI Controls
super.viewWillAppear(animated)